# fetch one to many side with jpql

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, jpql

so I have done two entities with one to many relationship,
I have one category whohas many visitors,
and this is my code:

this is the Category entity :

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

private Integer id;
private String name;
private List<Visitor> visitors = new ArrayList<Visitor>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", orphanRemoval = true)
public List<Visitor> getVisitors() {
    return visitors;
}

public void setVisitors(List<Visitor> visitors) {
    this.visitors = visitors;
}

}
```

and here is the Visitor Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Visitor extends User {

private String passport;
private String citizenship;
private String gender;
private Company company;
private Category category;  

public String getPassport() {
    return passport;
}

public void setPassport(String passport) {
    this.passport = passport;
}

public String getCitizenship() {
    return citizenship;
}

public void setCitizenship(String citizenship) {
    this.citizenship = citizenship;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}
```

and here is the service method who list all the visitors and works fine :

```
public List<Visitor> findAllVisitors() {
    return em.createQuery(
            "SELECT v from Visitor v left join fetch v.category",
            Visitor.class).getResultList();

}
```

with this method I can list all the visitors each with his category object associated,

now the problem is in the other side of the relationship , 
here is the method who list the categories each with their visitors list :

```
public List<Category> findAllCategories() {

    return em.createQuery("select c from Category c",
            Category.class).getResultList();
}
```

I want to get the list of all the categories but when I call this method in a REST call , I get this result :

[image]

I want just to get a simple list of categories (id and name).
what is wrong in my code please help me i am confused.

UPDATE:

this is how I get JSON from persistence context with RESTful method :

```
@Inject
private CategoryServiceLocal categoryServiceLocal;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Category> dofindAllCategories() {
    return categoryServiceLocal.findAllCategories();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lazy association from `Category` to `visitors`. To load all visitors you need to use `left join fetch` too.

```
select c from Category c left join fetch c.visitors
```

Please, use additional annotations to control how to `JSON` generated

[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: when I try this query I get an infinite result JSON !!

Comment: @majdhwas I update. You need to add annotations for JSON generator.

Comment: I am not working with Spring framework, so I can not use this annotations

Comment: @majdhwas How do you convert objects to `JSON`?

Comment: I updated my question to show you how I convert to JSON.

Comment: @majdhwas `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` this means that `JSON` is generated by some library. Just use corresponding annotations from that library.